# C#/.net API for RabbitMQ Management API

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

The Rabbit MQ Management Plugin exposes a REST API for management functions, I am specifically interested in the functions related to health monitoring like queue depth. Is there any C#/.net wrapper for the Management API? The only one I have found is the EasyNetQ library, however it only contains a limited set of functions exposed by the API.

Comment: ... I cannot believe they dont have an open api spec

Comment: @Stefan RabbitMQ is open-source software and we would gladly review pull requests to implement that. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeBakken I would love to help you out... but ideally you would auto gen it from the actual api methods (or even better; base the methods on the specs). This will have quite the impact on the project. Do you have a link to the repo?

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management

Answer (score 1):

There is this nuget package that gives you access to the REST api for your rabbitmq management server https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ.Management.Client